# SCD2 WITH FACT TABLE IMPLEMENTATION

Tags: sql, data-warehouse

I am asked to build a client dimension and a bed dimension .

and bring them together in the sense of clientID-SK,bedID_SK,Bed_begin_date,bed_end-date.Both tables contains SCD1, and SC2 fields.How do I implement this if the dates the clients was and out off bed and out  has nothing to do with what defines as a client or bed(types).

I have been able to combine them but my challenge is that when I load them into a fact table the
table only has the begin_date .How will I update the fact table end_date which is suppose to = the begin_date of the next bed assignment.

e.g
clientID,bedID,Start_Date,End_Date
10      ,ROO1, ,01-19-2020, 3000-01-01 00:00:00.000

Dimension
10      ,ROO1, ,01-19-2020, 10-19-2020
10      ,ROO2, ,10-19-2020, 3000-01-01 00:00:00.000

We have a table called current bed that keeps track of our current client and I was able to build a slowly changing dimension off that table.

But we are concerned to follow standard practice we have to have a star schema in place .

Any suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have, at least, the following tables:

1. Client Dimension holding all the client attributes
2. Bed Dimension holding all the Bed attributes
3. A Date Dimension
4. A Bed Occupancy Fact with FKs to Client Dim, Bed Dim and 2 FKs to Date Dim (one for Bed occupied and one for bed vacated)

When a bed is first occupied by a client you create a new fact record and populate the Client, Bed and Date Occupied FKs. You populate the Bed Vacated with 0 (or whatever key value you have used in the Date Dim to indicate the 'unknown' record).

When a bed is next occupied, you create a new fact record for the new client and update the Bed Vacated FK on the previous record with the relevant Date key.

A few things to think about:

1. Are you only working at the Date level of granularity or at Time level i.e. are you interested in what time of day (or morning/afternoon, etc.) when a bed was occupied/vacated?
2. I would ensure that the Date Vacated of the previous occupancy and the Date Occupied of the current one are not the same value otherwise you can get double counting on that overlapping date unless you start implementing logic to prevent it. For example, if a bed is occupied on the 25th Sept then set the Vacated date of the previous record to 24th Sept
3. Can you have periods when a bed is unoccupied? If you can, then I would create a fact record for this in exactly the same way as you would for an occupied bed but set the client ID FK to 0 (or whatever value you use in the client Dim to indicate a "not applicable" client)

Hope this helps?

**Update 1 following response**

If you need to include Time then you need a time dimension and 2 additional keys in the fact for occupied and vacated time.

I'm not sure I understand your question about how you update the fact table. You have the information required to identify the fact record (bed id and vacated date key = 0) and the value needed to update the fact record. What am I missing?

**UPDATE 2**

I think you need to take a step back and think clearly about what it is you are trying to achieve - then the answers to your questions should become more obvious.

The first question you need to ask is what are you trying to measure: once you have clearly defined that then the grain of the fact table is established and it becomes clearer what changes in attributes you need to handle. For example:

1. If you just want to know the status of a bed every time the occupant changes, and only the status of the occupant when they first use the bed (or last use the bed), then you only need to add a fact record when the bed occupancy changes and there is no need to record any updates during that patient's occupancy
2. If you want to know the state of of the bed at any point in time then first you need to define what you mean by "any point in time": every day, hour, minute, etc? Then you need to decide what you want to record if there are multiple changes in that time period i.e. the position at the start of the hour or the end of the hour. Based on these decisions, you then need to work out if there have been any changes during that time period and, if there have been, insert/update the relevant records
3. If you want to treat each patient's occupancy of a bed as a single fact then your fact record obviously has start and end dates but you also need to make the decision about which single state you are going to record for any attributes that can change over that period - you can record the patient's status at the start or end of the occupancy but not throughout the occupancy as that would affect the grain of the fact table

So to try and answer your questions...

If there is a change in dimension attributes and it affects your fact table then you'll need to handle this e.g. by inserting or updating a fact record:

- If you are only interested in the state of the patient at the start or end of the occupancy then any change to the patient's attributes during the occupancy can be ignored
- If you are interested in the state of the patient at any point in the occupancy then you'll need to make changes to the fact table whenever one of the patient's attributes changes

Records in your fact table should never overlap each other - so at any point in time there is only one active fact record per bed and per patient. Each time you insert a new fact record you would expire the previous applicable fact record.

So when you ask *"The update to the end_date when the client moves to a new bed will be on all 3 added surrogate key rows?"*, the answer is no - you would have set the end date on the first 2 records when you created the next record each time i.e. set the end date of record 1 when you create record 2, set the end date of record 2 when you create record 3, etc.; so you will only be updating the last record when the client moves.

Adding a PK to a fact table is only required when there is a requirement to update the fact table - as is the case here. Whether you do so is a choice - but I would look at how complicated the compound key is i.e. how many SKs do you need to use to identify the correct fact record to be updated. In you case you only need the Bed SK and the end_date = null (or 31/12/3000 or however you have chosen to set it) so there is probably no benefit in defining a single PK field on the fact table. If you needed more than about 5 SKs to identify a fact record then there is probably a case for using a single PK field.

## **UPDATE 3 - following comment added on 17/11/2020**

Mini-dimensions: just seem to be more, unnecessary complication but I can't really comment unless you can clearly articulate what the issue is that you think mini-dimensions will solve and why you think mini-dimensions are a solution to the issue

### Dates

You seem to be confused about the effective dates on an SDC2 dimension and foreign keys on a Fact table referencing the Date dimension - as they are very different things.

Date FKs on a Fact are attributes that you have chosen to record for that fact. In your example, for each bed occupancy fact (i.e. ***a single record*** in your fact table) you might have "Date Occupied" and "Date Vacated" attributes/FKs that reference the Date Dimension. When a fact record is created you would populate the "Date Occupied" field with the appropriate date and the "Date Vacated" with "0" (or whatever value points to the "Unknown" record in your Date Dimension). When the bed becomes unoccupied you update the fact record and set the "Date Vacated" field to the appropriate date.

Because you need to record 2 different dates against the fact, you need to have two FKs referencing the Date dimension; you couldn't record the Date Occupied and the Date Vacated using a single reference to the Date Dimension.

The same type of thinking applies when you want to have an FK on a fact table that references an SCD2 dimension; you need to decide what the point-in-time context of that reference is and then link to the correct version of the record in the SCD2 dimension. So if you want to record the state of the patient at the point they occupy the bed then you pick their record in the dimension where Fact.DateOccupied between Dim.EffStartDate and Dim.EffEndDate. If you want to *also* record the date of the patient at a different (but specific) time, such as when the bed was vacated, then you would need to add a separate FK to the fact table to hold this additional reference to the Patient Dim.

Having populated your fact table, if you want to know the state of the patient at a specific point in time you don't need to do anything to the fact table; instead you need to join the Patient Dim to itself. e.g.

1. The fact table holds an FK that references a record in the Patient Dim
2. From this Patient Dim record you can get the patient's BK
3. Join from this BK back to the Patient Dim and filter on the date that you want to get the patient's details for

Pseudo-code SQL for this would look something like (assuming you wanted to know the state of the patient on '2020-11-17'):

```
SELECT
    P2.*
FROM
    FACT_TABLE F
    INNER JOIN PATIENT_DIM P1
        ON F.PATIENT_SK = P1.PATIENT_SK
    INNER JOIN PATIENT_DIM P2
        ON  P1.PATIENT_BK         = P2.PATIENT_BK
            AND P2.EFFSTART_DATE <= '2020-11-17'
            AND P2.EFF_END_DATE  >= '2020-11-17'
```

Hope this helps?

Comment: When a bed is next occupied, you create a new fact record for the new client and Are you only working at the Date level of granularity or at Time level i.e. are you interested in what time of day (or morning/afternoon, etc.) when a bed was occupied/vacated?  Yes ,I am interested in the time as well.    How do I update the Bed Vacated? if the date is obtained  when the client moves to a different bed and lastly the final date is gotten from a different table.

Comment: I think to an extent I understand your explanation but in the case when there is a change in one of the attributes in the client for an scd2 field, that will enter the fact table as a new record right? because its a new surrogate key.How do we maintain such a situation since the client will still be in the same bed? .Eventually when the  client leaves that bed,how do we reference the proper row to update?since there are 2 rows with (bed id and vacated date key = 0) .Hope my question is clear?

Comment: You need to bear in mind that a fact is a measurable event and it is associated to attributes that describe that event. When deciding which version of a set of attributes is applicable to an event you basically have two options: the version that was applicable a the time of the event or the current version. If you chose one or the other then that will determine the SCD type for the dimensions you are building. If you want both that is also possible - but more complicated. If attributes change over time that is irrelevant to the fact records - unless it causes a new fact record to be created

Comment: What you can't do (without a lot of complication) is decide to apply the attributes in effect at a 'random' point in time to a fact

Comment: What if I am trying to use it as a factless table ?

Comment: See my previous comment "If attributes change over time that is irrelevant to the fact records - unless it causes a new fact record to be created". If you have a factless fact table then any change in attribute values will cause a new fact record to be created

Comment: I know you mentioned that a change in attribute is irrelevant but that is my main concern because I don't know if  my table which a type 2 SCD (may be I did not make that clear initially) should be added into the fact table as a new row or not  since its produces a new surrogate key in dimension and what do you suggest?

Comment: Please ,I just need clarity .So for each change in dimension either bed or patient there will be a new fact row included into the fact table? and for the update lets say there has been a change in client 3 times that means there are 3 records in dimension and 3 records in the fact table for the same bed assignment.The update to the end_date  when the client moves to a new bed will be on all 3 added surrogate key rows?,and do you suggest I add a natural key to the fact table in this case?

Comment: when you say the change in attribute can be ignored you meant 
Pat_SK| Bed_SK| Bed_Occupied | Bed_Vacated
2   | 1   | 01/02/2020 | 01/29/2020      
2   | 2  | 01/30/2020  | 0
Where Pat_SK =2 is the 2nd change in attribute                                                                                                          Pat_SK| Bed_SK| Bed_Occupied | Bed_Vacated
1  | 1 | 01/02/2020  | 01/29/2020      
2 | 1  | 01/02/2020  | 01/29/2020      
2 | 2  | 01/30/2020  | 0

Comment: No - that's not what I meant, I was giving an example: if you are only recording facts when a patient occupies and vacates a bed then any change to the patient after the point where they occupy the bed and before the point where they vacate it can be ignored because those changes are happening at points in time where you are not required to record facts. To try an reiterate the point I was making: you need to understand the reporting requirements you are being asked to support and from that you will be able to determine the grain of the facts you need to record and how you need to record them

Comment: @NickwW I have 2 questions ,will mini dimension be a good alternative option for the changing attributes?and for your response.Where I struggle with is ,that the dates in question are related to the bed assignment and not the dates the attributes changed .So how will I do an update to the end date when there is a change in attribute? i.e going the way of a fact-less table

Comment: Thank you very much Nick.Your explanation has given me a better understanding.Presently I am using merge to load the fact table from stage and I included a business key in the fact.when there is a change in attribute, I update the surrogate key in the fact table hence for the same bed assignment it maintains the updated version .Is that also practical?

Comment: I am using merge to load my fact table from stage.What is the best way to update the end date when a patient exit the hospital and not been transferred to a different bed.  The reference date data is coming from a different table(discharged table ) not present in the stage table that feeds the fact table?Hence in the stage table that patient in excluded.